# ASP.NET: About storing Objects in ViewState

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

If I want the object be persisted across postbacks, is it a good idea to store Object in ViewState? Are there any better ideas? I am afraid the size of ViewState is too large...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the object is too large, ViewState is a bad idea. Also there are other considerations regarding storing the information in the ViewState like security and how long you want the information to persist.

See [ASP.NET State Management Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx) for what other options you have.

Check [ASP.NET State Management Recommendations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx) to determine what to use in different scenarios.

I once stored a DataTable (facepalm) in the view state and was wondering why it took so much time load the page in a mobile browser. Storing it in session was MUCH faster because the page was not bloated with **unnecessary** objects.